# Why are listener and filter instances created automatically by tomcat container at start when a webapp is loaded?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I want to know the reason why listener and filter instances are created after loading the webapp by the Tomcat container. Why is eager loading instead of lazy loading specified in Servlet API?

Comment: what does you web.xml look like?

Comment: I have a SessionAttributeListener and a normal filter and a few servlets

Comment: did you mean why *default listeners* are created on tomcat's startup?

Comment: yes and also filters init method is called automatically

Comment: @deshmanthchennuri, 
after the container creates an instance of a filter, its init method will be called, that is a normal behaviour

Comment: @deshmanthchennuri, all system listeners get initialized on startup due to its importance for the system. E.g. the `GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener` - without this listener, none of the global resources will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Auto instantiation behavior is part of the servlet specification that all Servlet containers must uphold.

You can check it here http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/

Download the PDF.

> 6.2.1 Filter Lifecycle
>
> After deployment of the Web application, and before a request causes
>   the container to access a Web resource, the container must locate the
>   list of filters that must be applied to the Web resource as described
>   below. The container must ensure that it has instantiated a filter of
>   the appropriate class for each filter in the list, and called its
>   init(FilterConfig config) method.
>
> 11.2 Event Listeners
>
> Application event listeners are classes that implement one or more of
>   the servlet event listener interfaces. They are instantiated and
>   registered in the Web container at the time of the deployment of the
>   Web application. They are provided by the Developer in the WAR.

Comment: I want to know what may be the reasons for the specified behaviour